# htaccess rewritecond and rewrite rule not working properly

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect all `/admin` calls into subdomain with this two lines in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^admin [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ http://admin\.somedomain\.com/$1/ [R,L]
```

Well, nothing happens. It just ignores the redirect rule and shows content of /admin directory.

Just for reference (and to skip requests to paste my entire `.htaccess` file), here it is:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

Redirect 404 /favicon.ico

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^admin [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ http://admin\.somedomain\.com/$1/ [R,L]

# Send all admin. traffic to /admin
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^admin\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /admin/$1 [L]

# Check for www. and add it
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^admin\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]

# Add trailing slash if not found
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !favicon.ico
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/ [R,L]

# Process virtual links/directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/?$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %(HTTP_HOST} !^admin\.somedomain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://admin.somedomain.com$1 [R,L]
```

You were missing a leading slash on your RewriteCond match. With the assumption that admin.somedomain.com may be in the same configuration as the other domain, I also added a check to ensure the rule isn't applied if the domain is already admin.somedomain.com. In the RewriteRule, I made a couple of minor modifications: You aren't matching on the right side, so you don't need to escape the dots.

There are some issues with your remaining rules as well. This won't work, for example:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1
```

You can't use server variables on that side of the rule.

Comment: Strange part is, that your first fixed rules doesn't work, if I enter `www.somedomain.com/admin`, it doesn't redirect, but just shows the content of `/admin` directory. The second rule works (just tested).